# pandas datetime grouping by months, "TypeError: Categorical input must be list-like"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have date time ranges between two dates as follows:

I want to group them by 2 months.

```
date_time = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01',
              end='2022-12-31',
              freq='H')

res = date_time.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="2M"))

for r in res:
    print (r)
```

TypeError: Categorical input must be list-like

Comment: I tested above, when I `print(r)`, I get `TimeGrouper(freq=<2 * MonthEnds>, axis=0, sort=True, dropna=True, closed='right', label='right', how='mean', convention='e', origin='start_day')` so looks like it is working.  I'm using `pandas 1.5.0` and `python 3.10.6`. I also get this warning: `FutureWarning: Allowing scalars in the Categorical constructor is deprecated and will raise in a future version.  Use '[value]' instead
  res = date_time.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="2M"))`

Comment: @user3479780 I'm using python 3.9 and latest pandas and getting this error....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `groupby` on an index-like with a grouper key. You have to provide a full list of values. If you convert your `DatetimeIndex` to `Series` or `DataFrame`, you can use a `Grouper`:

```
# A smaller example
>>> date_time
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-01-01 01:00:00',
               '2022-01-01 02:00:00', '2022-01-01 03:00:00',
               '2022-01-01 04:00:00', '2022-01-01 05:00:00',
               '2022-01-01 06:00:00', '2022-01-01 07:00:00',
               '2022-01-01 08:00:00', '2022-01-01 09:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```

```
# You can't do this with Month because it's a non-fixed frequency
>>> date_time.groupby(date_time.floor('2H'))
{2022-01-01 00:00:00: [2022-01-01 00:00:00, 2022-01-01 01:00:00],
 2022-01-01 02:00:00: [2022-01-01 02:00:00, 2022-01-01 03:00:00],
 2022-01-01 04:00:00: [2022-01-01 04:00:00, 2022-01-01 05:00:00],
 2022-01-01 06:00:00: [2022-01-01 06:00:00, 2022-01-01 07:00:00],
 2022-01-01 08:00:00: [2022-01-01 08:00:00, 2022-01-01 09:00:00]}

# Detail about floor
>>> date_time.floor('2H')
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-01-01 00:00:00',
               '2022-01-01 02:00:00', '2022-01-01 02:00:00',
               '2022-01-01 04:00:00', '2022-01-01 04:00:00',
               '2022-01-01 06:00:00', '2022-01-01 06:00:00',
               '2022-01-01 08:00:00', '2022-01-01 08:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

# Another key to group. You have to provide a list of length equal to your Index
>>> np.repeat(np.arange(0, len(date_time), 2), 2)
array([0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8])
```

```
# Convert as Series to use a Grouper and group by Month
>>> date_time.to_series().groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2H'))
[(Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
  2022-01-01 00:00:00   2022-01-01 00:00:00
  2022-01-01 01:00:00   2022-01-01 01:00:00
  Freq: H, dtype: datetime64[ns]),
 (Timestamp('2022-01-01 02:00:00'),
  2022-01-01 02:00:00   2022-01-01 02:00:00
  2022-01-01 03:00:00   2022-01-01 03:00:00
  Freq: H, dtype: datetime64[ns]),
 (Timestamp('2022-01-01 04:00:00'),
  2022-01-01 04:00:00   2022-01-01 04:00:00
  2022-01-01 05:00:00   2022-01-01 05:00:00
  Freq: H, dtype: datetime64[ns]),
 (Timestamp('2022-01-01 06:00:00'),
  2022-01-01 06:00:00   2022-01-01 06:00:00
  2022-01-01 07:00:00   2022-01-01 07:00:00
  Freq: H, dtype: datetime64[ns]),
 (Timestamp('2022-01-01 08:00:00'),
  2022-01-01 08:00:00   2022-01-01 08:00:00
  2022-01-01 09:00:00   2022-01-01 09:00:00
  Freq: H, dtype: datetime64[ns])]
```